# Jquery Hide/Show not working in Firefox Only?

Tags: jquery, firefox, animation, html

first and foremost thank you in advance for any help!. I've tried to sort this out on my own for quite a while, and the only hope I see now is javascript, and I don't understand either language really, so hopefully someone can help me.

I've got the following code.

http://pastebin.com/dgmUSWtS

And I'm having the strangest issue. On my laptop, Firefox/Chrome/IE it works fine, on my Desktop, Chrome/IE it works fine, but Firefox just shows everything. I've asked a few friends as well, and they too see 'all the content'. Any help is appreciated as to what I've done wrong :|

For reference, I learned via this tutorial (which also does not work in FF on my desktop) I've made sure my FF is up to date, noscript is turned off, adblock disabled, I have no other clue. http://designgala.com/how-to-expand-collapse-toggle-div-layer-using-jquery/ . I assumed the tutorial would work regardless, but now I'm even more confused :|

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine, is a weird issue but i would bet the problem lies in the hosting you are using...

I've just tried your code in jsbin.com and it works fine... try by changing your hosting provider, even a free one should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

try `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`,  hope it will work, and try `ctrl+shift+k` its for console of firefox.. you will get so many hints..

Comment: yes.. @Werner i was having the same issue.. and i tried check [**my question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223750/show-hide-not-working-in-firefox-yet-working-in-all-other-browsers)