# show() hide() not working in firefox yet working in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Here I am calling one JavaScript function `hideanddisplay()` to hide and display the menu which is added by using `<tiles:insert>`...

The code where the function is used:

```
<td onclick="hideanddisplay()" class="productLogo" title="Click to Hide/Display Navigator">
    <span style="cursor:pointer">hiii <span style="color:#FFFFFF">gud morning</span></span>
</td>
```

By calling this function, the below piece of code should be hidden and shown, as per the requirement...

```
<td id="sohamMenu" valign="top" class="leftmenuBG">
    <div id="soham" class="TA" style="width:210px; height:500px; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll;">
        <tiles:insert attribute="menupage" />
    </div>
</td>
```

Here is the function for hide and display:

```
function hideanddisplay() {
    var cookiewval = getMyCookie("status");
    if (cookiewval == "hide") {
        $("#sohamMenu").show(500);
        document.cookie = "status=show;";
    } else {
        $("#sohamMenu").hide(500);
        document.cookie = "status=hide;";
    }

    function getMyCookie(name) {
        var prefix = name + "=";
        var start = document.cookie.indexOf(prefix)
        if (start == -1) {
            return null;
        }
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", start + prefix.length)
        if (end == -1) {
            end = document.cookie.length;
        }
        var tempString = document.cookie
        var value = tempString.substring(start + prefix.length, end)
        return unescape(value);
    }
```

Comment: if you're using jquery why not just use `toggle()` or `show()` and `hide()`?

Comment: place the code in JSfiddle or JSbin so that I can correct the problem

Comment: @rgin toggle is also not working properly in firefox....

Comment: You're probably missing something. Post a fiddle that replicates your issue and we'll take a look see. Because I know, for a fact, that jquery doesn't have any issues on firefox.

Comment: ok this might not be your cause, but I see some issues in JS (like first function is not closed). I hope they aren't there in your full code.

Comment: [**This jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/yvA8d/) seems to be working in FF.

Comment: in jsfiddle::  under html i put <td onclick="hideanddisplay()"><button>h</button></td>
<td id="sohamMenu" valign="top" class="leftmenuBG" >
<div id="soham"  class="TA" style="width:210px; height:500px; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll;"></div>
</td>

Comment: Unrelated: How come you call the menu Soham? He's angry I guess, lol. Okay, regarding to the question, did the script execute in the browser? Any alert? This ensure the element got triggered correctly.

Comment: and under JS i put whatever which is here...

Comment: @chaitanya: Your code (after correcting the error I mentioned earlier) seems to be working fine in FF for me too

Comment: try clearing your cache by CNTRL+R and then make a run

Comment: for me still its not working ... i also checked in fiddle.. in fiddle its working... but not in firefox...

Comment: @chaitanya that is strange. do you get any error in console? your FF version? is it the latest?

Comment: ya.. i checked... i didn't get any error regarding this code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the answer!!!! yoohooo...!!! Show() and hide() was not working for me.. i tried fadeIn() fadeOut()... bingo!!!

```
$("#sohamMenu").fadeIn(500);

$("#sohamMenu").fadeOut(500);
```